# Partial fraction decomposition with a nonrepeated irreducible quadratic factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I'm trying to do a partial fraction decomposition on the following rational eqn with a nonrepeated irreducible quadratic factor:

$$\dfrac{-28x^2-92}{(x-4)^2(x^2+1)}$$

I've broken it down into an identiy: $-28x^2 -92 = A((x-4)(x^2-1))+B(x^2+1)+(Cx+D)(x-4)^2$

and solved for B by setting x to 4 ($B-12$), distributed the -12 and moved the resulting quadratic to the left side, leaving me with:

$$12x^2-28x-80 =  A((x-4)(x^2-1)) + (Cx+D)(x-4)^2$$

Now I want to solve for A by setting x to something that will make the coefficient on $Cx+D$ zero, but I'm stumped - setting it to 4 also gets rid of my A. What do I do? Or have I messed up somewhere along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out an equation of A and c compare coefficient of $x^3$.put x=0 and compare coefficient of $x^2$.after doing these all operation you will find equation and some values.If you stuck then leave a comment.I'll do it.
 you have this eqn
$$-28x^2-92=A(x-4)(x^2+1)+B(x^2+1)+(Cx+D)(x-4)^2$$
then putting $x=4$ you will get $B=\dfrac{-540}{17}$

compare coefficient of $x^3$ you will get : $0=A+C$

compare coefficient of $x^2$ you will get : $-28=-4A+B-8C+D$

putting  $x=0$ you will get: $-92=-4A+B+16D$

you have value of B so these eqn will become litte more  easy and I hope you will take it to final from now on.

Comment: Interesting, you're telling me to equate the coefficients of like powers of x? I've done this for other problems - should I have done this from the beginning? More specifically: Should I have started by distributing the identity I got, distributed/collected like terms and equated coefficients of like powers, rather than solving for B as I did?

Comment: ok i am solving it wait 5 min

Comment: btw you are right to do as for B but the value is too much complicated can I just give you equation?

Comment: Yes, please... :) And thanks!

Comment: Got it, thanks again!

Comment: @drewmore your welcome buddy

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have done...

$$\dfrac{-28x^2-92}{(x-4)^2(x^2+1)} 
= \dfrac{A}{(x-4)} + \dfrac{B}{(x-4)^2} + \dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$$

$$-28x^2 -92 = A(x-4)(x^2+1) + B(x^2+1) + (Cx+D)(x-4)^2$$

Letting $x=4$, we get

$$-540 =17B$$

$$B = -\dfrac{540}{17}$$

What I would do now...

Let $B = -\dfrac{540}{17}$ and simplify.

\begin{align}
   17(-28x^2 -92) &= 17A(x-4)(x^2+1) - 540(x^2+1) + 17(Cx+D)(x-4)^2 \\
   64(x^2-16) &= 17A(x-4)(x^2+1) + 17(Cx+D)(x-4)^2 \\
   64(x+4) &= 17A(x^2+1) + 17(Cx+D)(x-4) \\
\end{align}

Again, let $x=4$...

$$512 = 289A$$

$$A = \dfrac{512}{289}$$

Finally. let $A = \dfrac{512}{289}$ and simplify one more time...

\begin{align}
   64(x+4) &= \dfrac{512}{17}(x^2+1) + 17(Cx+D)(x-4) \\
   1088(x+4) &= 512(x^2+1) + 289(Cx+D)(x-4) \\
   -64(8x+15)(x-4) &= 289(Cx+D)(x-4) \\
   -64(8x+15) &= 289(Cx+D) \\
   -\dfrac{512x}{289} - \dfrac{960}{289} &= Cx+D
\end{align}

$$C = -\dfrac{512}{289}$$

$$D = - \dfrac{960}{289}$$